# Insert Into (select from ) with multifield values and specific values

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to insert mulivalues of swab locations into a table that has the same tracking number. Here is the example:

tblMainSwapLocation (Table where i get my information form)

```
Asset_ID  MAterial   Swap_Location
MFG111    Brick      Top left
MFG111    Plastic    Top right
MFG113    Wood       Center
```

tblCVLocation (Table where i want to insert information into)

```
TrackingID  Asset_ID   Swap_Location
99801       MFG111     Top left
99801       MFG111     Top right
```

I am using the following sql query to do the job, but i am having troubles with how the query should be.

```
strSQL = "Insert Into tblCVProject " & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Values ( [pTrackNum], (SELECT MEQ.Asset_ID ,MEQ.SwabLocation" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM tblMainSwapLocation as MEQ " & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE MEQ.Asset_ID = [pAsset_ID] ))"
Debug.Print strSQL
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)
qdf.Parameters("pAssetID").Value = Me.cboAsset_Id
qdf.Parameters("pTrackNum").Value = TrackNum
```

The query in simplier form, It runs when the user clicks the save button.

```
Insert Into tblCVProject 
Values ( [pTrackNum], (SELECT MEQ.Asset_ID ,MEQ.SwabLocation, MEQ.Equipment_Name 
FROM tblMainSwapLocation as MEQ 
WHERE MEQ.Asset_ID = [pAsset_ID] ))
```

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the INSERT statement is well explained at:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx
```

Either use `VALUES` (for single-record append query) or `SELECT` for multi-record append query.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough info to give a clear answer.

I have guessed that your TrackingID  column is defined as auto-number because I see nowhere a source for it

If you want to generate a record in tblCVLocation for each tblMainSwapLocation then you just have to do this :

```
INSERT INTO tblCVProject  ([Asset_ID],[Swap_Location])
SELECT Asset_ID, Swap_Location FROM tblMainSwapLocation
```

If you want to insert only for some Asset_ID or material, then add a WHERE clause after the SELECT
If you want only the distinct pairs of Asset_ID + Swap_location then add a  DISTINCT clause in the SELECT

I really can be more accurate with the information specified

Comment: The use of distinct has helped me overcome some problems, but the main issues i had was with the syntax of VALUES VS SELECT, i didnt realise that untill cisco pointed out that to me